# Type R.drawable.stat_notify_calendar cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a notification in Android. But i get the error in the title by using:

```
   Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_calendar, tickerText,
           System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Do i need to define something before i try to draw it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that to work, you need an image in `res/drawable/` (or a related resource set) named `stat_notify_calendar.*` where the `*` could be `png`, `jpg`, etc.